# Sigma algebra generated by algebra

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-sets

Let $(X, \mathcal X , \mu)$ and $(Y, \mathcal Y, \nu)$ are two meaure spaces and let $\mathcal Z$ is the sigma algebra that generated by $P=AxB$ sets where $A \in \mathcal X$ and $B \in \mathcal Y$. $\mathcal {Z_0}$ is family of finite unions of $P$ sets.

I’ve shown that  $\mathcal {Z_0}$ is an algebra. I’d like to learn that is  $\mathcal Z$ sigma algebra generated by  $\mathcal {Z_0}$ algebra? How can I show it? I couldn’t understanf these concepts well. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathcal A$ be the  sigma algebra generated by $\mathcal Z_0$. Let us show that $\mathcal A$ is contained in $\mathcal Z$ and that $\mathcal A$ is contains in $\mathcal Z$. Since  $\mathcal Z$ is  a sigma algebra  and it contains sets of the form $A \times B$ it also contains finite unions of these. Hence it contains $\mathcal A$ (because the latter is the smallest sigma algebra containing the sets $A \times B$).

On the other hand  $\mathcal A$  is a sigma algebra which contains all finite unions of the sets $A\times B$ and hence it also contains sets of the type  $A\times B$. Since $\mathcal Z$ is the  smallest sigma algebra containing these sets we get $\mathcal Z \subseteq\mathcal A$